# Install packages on elementary OS with downgrade

Tags: release-freya, software-installation, apt, aptitude

I've been grappling with installing some Ubuntu packages with `apt-get` so I thought I'd post an example for anyone else struggling with Elementary OS. Here `libssl` or `openssl` won't install and these are dependencies I need for R packages. I suspect this is because I have added Ubuntu PPA's and updated already.

Note that reinstalling with `apt-get remove` or `apt-get install -f` does not resolve this.

[image: ssl_question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be resolved by installing aptitude with:

`sudo apt-get install aptitude`

Then running

`sudo aptitude install libssl-dev`

and selecting the options as follows.

[image: ssl_answer]